How does wrap_unicode option work when ffmpeg renders subtitles
This is my complete command, which accepts the wrap_unicode option, but the option is not working
'/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'input.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'aac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-vf' '[in]subtitles=test.srt:wrap_unicode=1:force_style='\''FontSize=12,FontName=Angsana New,PrimaryColour=&H00FFFFFF,BorderStyle=1,Outline=0.5,Shadow=1,MarginV=50'\''[out]' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/var/folders/xh/0xpfqmh57hb12ffvs5wy1v0w0000gn/T/ffmpeg-passes66e24b16ea0aa/pass-66e24b16ea47b' 'output.mp4'

Before that, I compiled libunibreak, libass(0.17.0) in order, and reinstalled ffmpeg.
I hope someone can help me understand where the problem caused this option to not take effect, this problem has been bothering me for some time, thank you very much!

This is srt file contents:
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:04,000
这是一个非常长的中文字幕示例，显示在屏幕上时如果没有自动换行就会超出屏幕宽度。
2
00:00:05,000 --> 00:00:08,000
これは画面幅を超えるほど長い日本語の字幕の例です。自動的に改行されない場合、読みづらくなります。
